# C++ lambda expression meaning

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I am learning lambda expression in C++. I found the below code at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp

```
     #include <iostream>  
     using namespace std;  

     int main()  
     {  
          int m = 0;  
          int n = 0;  
          [&, n] (int a) mutable { m = ++n + a; }(4);  
          cout << m << endl << n << endl;  
     }
```

The output:
         5
         0

I cannot understand (4) at the line of lambda expression. What does this (4) means and how it is used in the lambda expression?

Comment: The `4` is passed as an argument to the lambda function.  Inside the function, it is represented by `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to

```
int m = 0;
int n = 0;

void f(int a)
{
    m = n + 1 + a;
}

int main()
{
    f(4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression `[&, n] (int a) mutable { m = ++n + a; }` creates a temporary callable object. The `(4)` part is simply "calling" that object, passing `4` as the argument.

The whole expression `[&, n] (int a) mutable { m = ++n + a; }(4)` is roughly equivalent to

```
auto temporary_function_object = [&, n] (int a) mutable { m = ++n + a; };
temporary_function_object(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplified code. Variable `m` will be captured by reference and variable `n` will be captured by value in the lambda.

Since it is declared mutable variable n will not be affected outside the lambda. Hence you get 5 and 0 for `m` and `n`. If you use `[=]` it will print 0 0

```
 #include <iostream>  
 using namespace std;  

 int main()  
 {  
      int m = 0;  
      int n = 0;  
      auto func = [&, n] (int a) mutable { m = ++n + a; };  
      func(4);
      cout << m << endl << n << endl;  
 }
```

So.

```
  auto func =[]() { cout << " Hello \n"; }; // this is similar to func definition
   func(); // call here to execute
```

Or you can directly call like this :

```
[]() { cout << " Hello \n"; }();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fundamentals are clear about Lambda then it would be simpler for you like

```
[&, n] (int a) mutable { m = ++n + a; }(4);
```

1. capture list i.e `[&,n]` suggest capturing everything as reference & `n` as value.
2. `(int a)` represent argument list.
3. `mutable` keyword suggest you can mutate captured value of n withing closure. In other words, `this` pointer would be mutable.
4. `(4);` at the end calls the lambda function with passing argument `4`.

I have written one article on the same -> [Lambda function in C++ with example](http://www.vishalchovatiya.com/learn-lambda-function-in-cpp-with-example/). If you have time you can consider it.